# javascript: get contents of textarea, textContent vs. innerHTML vs. innerText

Tags: javascript, textarea, getelementbyid

I am having trouble getting the contents of a textarea with js.  I feel like I've done this many times before without problems but something is throwing it off or I have a mental block.

html

```
<textarea id="productdescript">test copy..asdfd</textarea><button value="Enter" onclick="addProduct()">
```

js

```
function addProduct() {
var descript = document.getElementById('productdescript').textContent;
alert(descript);
}
```

Firefox is the only browser I have currently.

When I use textContent, the alert box appears but it is blank.
When I use value, the alert box appears and says "Undefined"
When I use innerHTML, all the HTML appears including the  tags.

Also, I understand that textContent only runs in FF and for cross browser compatibility you need to do something like innerText and textContent but textContent is not working in FF.  There is no jquery on this app

What is the correct cross browser way to get contents of textarea!  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For `textarea`, you could only use `.value` in your scenario (I tested your given code and it works fine).
.

Also,

1) keep in mind that you call this function `addProduct()` **ONLY** after your element is mentioned in the code, otherwise it will be `undefined`.

2) there must **not** be another element with `id as productdescript`

3) there must not be a JS `variable` called `productdescript`

Comment: that was a typo in my question.  Thx!  The code actually had the lowercase d but still exhibiting above problems.

Comment: any idea why it alerts "Undefined" when I use .value?

Comment: addProduct is called after mention of id, I believe.

Comment: Then there must be another element in the html code with the id as `productdescript`. Check view source.

Comment: you were right, there was another id with same name.  .value worked

Comment: I was wondering *why* `textContent` doesn't work, because it seems like it should. Turns out it's [WAI](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.support.firefox/sv0MUeBzLLo/Y64F6WXsYYwJ): "textContent returns the text content in the DOM - not the current
value of the control"

Comment: Using `input` instead of `keyup` is much better because the keyup triggers after the text is written, making the text glitch through the height before it is resized. Therefore the `input` event is better and I suggest using it.

Answer (score 1):

This are your code?

you write `document.getElementByID....` and the "D" should be written lowercase "d"

```
document.getElementById('productdescript').textContent;
```